# Rshiny: How to view dataframes side by side(left and right)

Tags: r, shiny

I'd want to see the data frames data_A and data_B side by side, but it just shows data A right now.

Currently, it shows me the below error message.

I'm having trouble figuring out where I made a mistake, and I'm new to R shiny, so could someone please assist me?

My code:

```
library(shiny)

DF1 <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:5),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,735.0,844.25))


DF2 <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:6),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary", "Alex"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25, 243.5))


DF3 <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:7),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary", "Alex", "Christan"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25, 243.5, 600.0))



shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      selectInput("dataset5", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "DF1", "DF2", "DF3")),
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table5")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset5,
             "DF1" = DF1,
             "DF2" = DF2,
             "DF3" = DF3)
    })
    output$table5 <- renderTable({
      datasetInput()
    })
    
  }
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Ronak Shah, thank you for your comment. I've modified my code above, and I'm attempting to display data tables emp.data_A and emp.data_B side by side. How it should be done?

Comment: Is it possible to have a single dropdown menu? So that both the dataframes should be visible?

Comment: @RonakShah Any suggestions?

Comment: @RonakShah, Any Idea?

Comment: For example, if I have three data frames named DF1, DF2, and DF3, I must show DF 1 and DF2 separately. But I also need to show the difference( in values) between DF1 and DF2 by selecting DF3.

Comment: @RonakShah, I have edited my code. I have DF1, DF2, and DF3 in the options of choice. However, when I choose DF3, it should show DF1 and DF3 side by side for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this -

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      fluidRow(column(6, selectInput("dataset1", "Choose first dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "DF1", "DF2", "DF3"))),
      
      column(6, selectInput("dataset2", "Choose second dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "DF1", "DF2", "DF3")))
      ),
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(column(6,  tableOutput("table1")), 
               column(6,  tableOutput("table2"))
               )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    datasetInput1 <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset1,
             "DF1" = DF1,
             "DF2" = DF2,
             "DF3" = DF3)
    })
    
    datasetInput2 <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset2,
             "DF1" = DF1,
             "DF2" = DF2,
             "DF3" = DF3)
    })
    
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
      datasetInput1()
    })
    
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
      datasetInput2()
    })
    
  }
)
```